# Google Apps Script no escribe en una hoja de cálculo

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

En mi empresa me están solicitando un nuevo formulario para una encuesta,tengo la interfaz realizada y una hoja de calculo de prueba en drive que la estoy desarrollando en script.google., el inconveniente es cuando intento escribir en la hoja de calculo, no he encontrado en que parte de las guías de google que me sirva el código script es

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //llamada a la función getValuesFromForm con los input's como argumentos
   function formSubmit() {

google.script.run.getValuesForm(
document.getElementById("nombreEvento").value,

document.getElementById("nombreSolicitante").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("emailSolicitante").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("servicio").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("fechaEvento").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("horaInicio").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("horaFin").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("organiza").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("nombreResponsable").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("cargo").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("telefono").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("celular").value,  
                                        document.getElementById("responsableTecnico").value, 
                                        document.getElementById("emailTecnico").value);
    }
```

y el la funcion de gs es

```
function getValuesFrom(nombreEvento, nombreSolicitante, emailSolicitante, servicio, fechaEvento, horaInicio, horaFin, organiza, nombreResponsable, cargo, telefono, celular, responsableTecnico, emailTecnico, difusion){  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("******").getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(nombreEvento);
sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue(nombreSolicitante);
sheet.getRange(1,4).setValue(emailSolicitante);
sheet.getRange(1,5).setValue(servicio);
sheet.getRange(1,6).setValue(fechaEvento);
sheet.getRange(1,7).setValue(horaInicio);
sheet.getRange(1,8).setValue(horaFin);
sheet.getRange(1,9).setValue(organiza);
sheet.getRange(1,10).setValue(nombreResponsable);
sheet.getRange(1,11).setValue(cargo);
sheet.getRange(1,12).setValue(telefono);
sheet.getRange(1,13).setValue(celular);
sheet.getRange(1,14).setValue(nombreSolicitante);  
sheet.getRange(1,15).setValue(responsableTecnico);
sheet.getRange(1,16).setValue(emailTecnico);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estás complicando. Te dejo por aquí el código que yo usaría para tú caso:

Lo primero de todo sería modificar tu google script:

```
function doGet(e){
  var op = e.parameter.action;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Link de tu SpreadSheet");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if(op=="insert")
    return insert_value(e,sheet);
}

function insert_value(request,sheet){
   var nombreEvento = request.parameter.nombreEvento;
  var nombreSolicitante = request.parameter.nombreSolicitante;
    var servicio = request.parameter.servicio;
  var cargo = request.parameter.cargo;
  var celular = request.parameter.celular;

  var flag=1;
  var lr= sheet.getLastRow();

  if(flag==1){
  var d = new Date();
    var currentTime = d.toLocaleString();
  var rowData = sheet.appendRow([currentTime,nombreEvento,nombreSolicitante,servicio,cargo,celular]);  
  var result="Insertion successful";
  }
     result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   
  }

  //https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID_DEL_SCRIPT!!!/exec?nombreEvento=a&nombreSolicitante=b&servicio=c&cargo=d&celular=f&action=insert
```

Lo segundo sería el método de inserción:

```js
  var script_url = "Link de tu Script";
    function insert_value() {
        var id1 = $("#id").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var city = $("#city option:selected").val();
        var url = script_url + "?callback=Verificacion&name=" + name + "&id=" + id1 + "&email=" + email + "&city=" + city + "&action=insert";
        var request = jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
        $("#resetForm").reset();
    }
    function Verificacion(e) {
        alert('Congrats! Registered Successfully')
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-top">
        <div class="top-flex-item1">
        <div class="form-container" id="booknow" align="center">
            <div class="form-class">Demo<span style="font-size:3.2vw;">&#9786;</span>
                <div style="margin-top:15px">
                    <form autocomplete=off action="javascript:;" id="resetForm" onsubmit="insert_value()">
                        <input type="text" class="book-now" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br />

                        <input type="number" id="id" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;" class="book-now" placeholder="Enter your 10 digit mobile number" required><br />
                        <select id="city" class="select-custom" id="city" name="city">
            <option class="options-custom" value="A2">A2</option>
            <option class="options-custom" value="A3">A3</option>
            <option class="options-custom" value="A5">A5</option>
            <option class="options-custom" value="A6">A6</option>
            <option class="options-custom" value="V">V</option>
        </select><br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Register Now" onclick="location.href='2.html';"><br />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

En el Google Script he agregado alguna de tus variables, falta que agregues las que faltan.

El HTML no tiene ninguna de tus variables ya que no tengo ahora mismo no tengo mucho tiempo para modificarlo, pero sustituye y agrega tus variables. No te olvides de modificar el JS y agregar por ejemplo la variable de servicios (servicios + "&servicios=").

Eso sería todo.